# Usar LEAD para pegar a próxima data

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Estou tentando montar uma consulta que responda a seguinte pergunta:

Quantidade de clientes (inscrição no caso) que tem data de leitura de 26 dias, quantidade de clientes que tem leitura de 27 dias e por aí vai até 31 dias, vou mostrar uma imagem exatamente do que quero:

[image: Preciso que fique desse jeito]

A minha consulta não está retornando o que quero, ela está retornando zero em toda coluna de QTD_DIAS, a consulta está conforme a imagem (eu coloquei após o order by a dat_leitura, ta)

Então, eu acredito que precise fazer algum tipo de subquery, mas não sei por onde começar, alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado, muito obrigado!

```
select distinct top 10 sigla_unidade AS UNIDADE
                , dsc_localidade as LOCALIDADE
                , o.competencia AS COMPETENCIA
                --, DAT_LEITURA AS QTD_DIAS
                , lead(dat_leitura, 1) over (PARTITION by dat_leitura order by) prox_leitura
                , datediff(day, dat_leitura, lead(dat_leitura, 1) over(PARTITION by dat_leitura)) QTD_DIAS
                , o.inscricao as QTD_INSCRICOES
from BASE o
join USUARIOS u 
on o.inscricao = u.inscricao
join UNIDADES n
on u.cod_und_negocio = n.cod_unid_negocio
join LOCALIDADES 1
on u.localidade = 1.cod_localidade
--group by sigla_unidade, desc_localidade, o.competencia, dat_leitura, a.inscricao
```

Comment: O número de inscrição do cliente é por unidade/localidade ou é geral? Isto é, pode ter mais de um cliente com o mesmo número de inscrição, mas em unidades (ou localidades) diferentes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando-se as informações fornecidas até o momento, eis sugestão:

```
-- código #1
with Base2 as (
SELECT *,
       datediff(day,
                lag(dat_leitura, 1) over (partition by inscricao order by competencia),
                dat_leitura
               ) as QTD_DIAS
  from BASE
)
SELECT sigla_unidade AS UNIDADE,
       dsc_localidade as LOCALIDADE,
       o.competencia AS COMPETENCIA,
       QTD_DIAS,
       count(*) as QTD_INSCRICOES
  from BASE2 as o
       join USUARIOS as u on o.inscricao = u.inscricao
       join UNIDADES as n on u.cod_und_negocio = n.cod_unid_negocio
       join LOCALIDADES as l on u.localidade = l.cod_localidade
  where QTD_DIAS between 26 and 31
  group by sigla_unidade, desc_localidade, o.competencia, QTD_DIAS;
```